How to avoid empty columns in a css grid
I'm working on a grid layout where I have content cards of varying sizes (small and medium). The grid items are dynamically generated, and I want to avoid empty gaps by rearranging them, such that a medium-sized card moves up to fill the first row, and a small card shifts down to avoid gaps.
I was expecting that the css property grid-auto-flow: dense would do the trick. Is there a css property that can do the work for me instead of writing a solution in JS.
Expected result:
First row: [Small Card, Medium Card] (total 3 columns filled)
Second row: [Small Card, empty, empty]


<html>
<style>
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.medium_card, .small_card {
  padding: 12px;
}

.wrapper div.small_card {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper div.medium_card {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="small_card">Small Card 1 (span 1)</div>
  <div class="small_card">Small Card 2 (span 1)</div>
  <div class="medium_card">Medium Card (span 2)</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




No, CSS isn't going to automatically reorder the elements for you.

The order property enables implementation.


.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.medium_card,
.small_card {
  padding: 12px;
}
.small_card:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 2;
}
.medium_card {
  order: 1;
}

.wrapper div.small_card {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper div.medium_card {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="small_card">Small Card 1 (span 1)</div>
    <div class="small_card">Small Card 2 (span 1)</div>
    <div class="medium_card">Medium Card (span 2)</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



